# Angular app within dotnet core. Pages don not update changes on a file being changed

Tags: angular, build, .net-core, angular-cli

I have an angular (version 6.1.5) app created inside a dotnet project. 
I followed this: http://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-create-an-angular-6-app-with-visual-studio-2017/ 
tutorial to create the project. Works fine except, when I change a file, like for example updating an html file from:

`<ng-template ngbTabTitle><b>Fancy</b> title</ng-template>`

to

`<ng-template ngbTabTitle><b>josh</b> title</ng-template>`

when I do this the page does not update to show the changes.
I think the problem is due to the application being compiled by dotnet rather than the angular cli. because if I go to the command line and cd into the project and run `ng serve -o` , and do the same thing (change a small thing in the html file and save it), then I see the changes updated immediatly in the browser.

other theory could something be wrong with inotify? idk.

thanks for any help someone can provide.